# C++ CMakeLists how to build dependencies only once?

Tags: c++, cmake, build, dependencies, artificial-intelligence

I installed some libraries with:

```
sudo apt-get install libomp-dev
sudo apt-get install libarmadillo-dev
sudo apt-get install libmlpack-dev
```

When I try to build/execute/debug the app in eclipse it seems it builds all the dependencies again. It takes long time for a simple program. Dependencies in CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)
target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} INTERFACE -fopenmp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX mlpack PUBLIC armadillo)
```

Program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mlpack/core.hpp>
#include <mlpack/methods/ann/layer/layer.hpp>
#include <mlpack/methods/ann/ffn.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace mlpack;
using namespace mlpack::ann;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    cout << "Hello World." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Since these dependencies are not modified, there is a way to avoid building them each time that I want to execute/debug my "hello world"? Something like: Build dependencies only once. Or: Build only if don't exist (Clean and build).

The result:

```
Building in: /home/ai/Documents/ai_projects/test1/build/default
cmake --build . --target all
Scanning dependencies of target Prueba_1
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test1.dir/test1.cpp.o  <-- It takes 40sec
[100%] Linking CXX executable test1
[100%] Built target test1
Build complete (0 errors, 0 warnings): /home/ai/Documents/ai_projects/test1/build/default
```

Answer (score 1):

> Since these dependencies are not modified, there is a way to avoid building them each time that I want to execute/debug my "hello world"? Something like: Build dependencies only once. Or: Build only if don't exist (Clean and build).

Sort of. CMake isn't actually building these libraries from scratch, so there's nothing to tell it about dependencies-wise. It's just that the headers are very large and take a long time to process.

However, you can often use *precompiled headers* as a workaround. Try this:

```makefile
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

# ...

target_precompile_headers(
  ${PROJECT_NAME}
  PRIVATE
    <iostream>
    <mlpack/core.hpp>
    <mlpack/methods/ann/layer/layer.hpp>
    <mlpack/methods/ann/ffn.hpp>
)
```

This will precompile these headers as a separate build step and include the result via a command line flag into every source file in the `${PROJECT_NAME}` target. This won't help on the *first* build, but when doing an *incremental* build, then as long as the set of includes in the precompiled header hasn't changed, you should see some benefit.